# Query previous row value and merge to current row

Tags: mysql

Is there a way how can I query the previous row value and merge to current row, here is my sample table scenario:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| ColA | ColB | ColValue |    Date    |
|------|------|----------|------------| 
| AAA  | 111  |     5    | 2017-04-23 |
| AAA  | 111  |     4    | 2017-04-22 |
| AAA  | 111  |     3    | 2017-04-21 |
| BBB  | 222  |     5    | 2017-04-30 |
| BBB  | 222  |     4    | 2017-04-29 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

And my expected result should be this, just want to get the previous and current value and group it by selected columns and date.

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| ColA | ColB | PreValue |  CurValue  |    Date    |
|------|------|----------|-------------------------| 
| AAA  | 111  |     4    |     5      | 2017-04-23 |
| AAA  | 111  |     3    |     4      | 2017-04-22 |
| AAA  | 111  |    N/A   |     3      | 2017-04-21 |
| BBB  | 222  |     4    |     5      | 2017-04-30 |
| BBB  | 222  |    N/A   |     4      | 2017-04-29 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

any suggestions or solution, thanks in advance

Here is my actual query from my actual data as reference:

```
SELECT ai.APName, tbap.Value , tbap.DateTime, tbap.Comment, tbap.ModifiedBy, tbap.ToolName, d.Name as Strategy FROM (SELECT dt.*,ins.Value as ToolName FROM (SELECT av.*,ai.DocumentID,ai.IndexID FROM ControlAutomation.appartitionindexes ai
JOIN (SELECT * FROM ControlAutomation.appartitionvalues
where DateTime > '2017-04-22 23:17:13' and DateTime < '2017-04-26 23:18:28') av
ON ai.APPartitionID = av.APPartitionID) dt INNER JOIN factory.indexes ins ON ins.ID = dt.IndexID
where dt.comment  like '%updateAdjustableParameter%'
group by dt.ID) tbap
INNER JOIN ControlAutomation.documents d ON d.ID =  tbap.DocumentID 
INNER JOIN appartitionindexes ai ON ai.APPartitionID = tbap.APPartitionID
GROUP BY tbap.ID
ORDER BY tbap.ToolName DESC, d.Name, tbap.DateTime DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key in the table ? or in other words to know which is previous value. Since the given example table AAA has all 23rd as date and there is no way to know which one is first

Comment: Why do you need this output, which may require using session variables?

Comment: Actually in my real data the Date columns is unique and I'm using it as my primary, so that's why it needs to group by date first then another is colA then colB

Comment: @Rockn'Roll the given sample table is having same date across all rows. So please correct that if its not the case. Also do you need to consider both colA and colB combination for match or has some different logic ?

Comment: I changed the table and expected result the Date should be unique

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Hope I correctly got your question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d815c/6

```
select
  prev_query.cola as ColA,
  prev_query.colb as ColB,
  rhs.colvalue as PreValue,
  prev_query.colvalue as CurValue,
  prev_query.coldate as ColDate
from
  prev_query left join prev_query as rhs
    on prev_query.cola = rhs.cola 
    and prev_query.colb = rhs.colb 
    and prev_query.colvalue = rhs.colvalue + 1
order by
  prev_query.cola, prev_query.colb, prev_query.coldate desc;
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution but before I get my result it was came from different tables. I want to create it as view but I don't have any admin rights to the db, so I used it as sub query. and when trying to do your left join gives me that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: I updated my question and post my actual query and struggling to inject your logic to my query, hope will help as reference, and it only focus in tbap.Value column.

Comment: @Rockn'Roll Can you provide a working sqlfiddle with some data?